# Django - How can I manage custom payments between users on my platform with Stripe?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a platform with multiple functionalities, and one of them is a crowfunding of projects, in which the users can post a project and ask for funds. (like kickstarter or indiegogo).

I'm working with Django 2.0, Python 3.6 and PostgreSQL and I want to use Stripe for payments. I also read a bunch of the [Stripe's API Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs), and I have some ideas for doing this, but this will be my first API implementation so I would like to do it well (more even talking about payment systems).

The main question is: **How can I do that multiple users realize payments to another for one project ONLY when the goals of that project are reached?**

- What I think that is the better is to use (Stripe Connect) Express/Custom Accounts to create an account for each user that posts a Project, so I can redirect all the payments to that account.

The thing is that **I also want to apply a fee for my platform.**

- And I don't know exactly how can I do this. I imagine that Stripe give an option for that to evade doing two transactions in my own backend (one for the project's user and another for the platform (me).

Then I have another related problem that is **when should I do the transactions?**

- I have to asure the 100% of the transactions, but also that the project get the funds only when it reach the goals, So I don't know if with Stripe I can freeze all the funds and then give it to the project or refund it depending on the state of the project goals.

As an alternative comes to my mind to put all the funds to an a sub-bank account of my own platform and then if the project reach the funds, do the transaction to the user's account; or if the project fails, make a full refund. The problem I see here is that if the project succeed, Stripe get's x2 times a transaction commission, and if the project fails, I (my platform) have to pay for my own the first transaction's Stripe commission. So this is not t.he correct answer at all.

> Kickstarter (as a main example) only do the transaction when the
>   project reach the funding goals, but doing that, they can (and
>   usually) get some failed transactions. This is what I cannot accept in
>   my platform.

To sum up, **I want be able to make that an user can pay to another only when the project goals are reached, get a commission for it and asure that the 100% of the transactions are accepted.**

I would like to ask for help in the coding (or tips at least) because I also read the documentation of [dj-stripe](https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe) and [pinax-stripe](https://github.com/pinax/pinax-stripe), but I don't see the way of doing what I need because their documentation is based on simple payments always to the same user and for subscriptions.

I think that maybe the best option is to use the [python api](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python) given by Stripe.

I also searched a lot for this and found the following things: [Crowdao](https://github.com/jellegerbrandy/crowdao), a project with stripe integrated for crowdfunding BUT is only for one project, so it doesn't solve the problem; A [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469058/basic-questions-for-django-ach-with-stripe?rq=1) of doing AHC with [Django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#stripe) and Stripe, but I don't see exactly how they do that, and I want to use more payment systems too, so I imagine it doesn't fit as a good answer for my problem.

If you need any extra information please ask for it, I'll do whatever I can. Thank you very much.

Comment: With commercial software like Stripe, I find the answer usually comes from making contact and asking them how to do what you want.  Ideally, they have applications engineers who know the ins and outs, and can tell you if what you want to do is possible, and how to do it - or if it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use stripe connect and when creating the charge use authorize-only (Note: Max 7 days)

Answer (score 0):

As @Oscar has suggested, connect[0] is the way to go.

So basically yourself will registered as a `platform` account and each projects will be registered as `connected` account, most likely custom/express type[1]. Your end user accounts who is contributing to each projects will live in your main platform account.

There are many ways to achieve your goal by charging the customer when goal is met. but One way is that  So you can do a `Destination Charge` [2] and a `Manual Payout`[3].

Basically 
In Destination charge, you charge the user $100 and transfer $80 to the connected project account; so you keep $20 as a fee; 
The $80 sits on the project stripe account's balance which is not paid out to their bank account. 
If the goal reaches, you trigger a manual payout to the project so that the project actually get the $80 dollars
If not, you will need to perform on refund[4] on all the transactions on that project.

That's it. 
Take note the manual payout only hold for 90 days, after that it moves out directly 
Your account will bear all the fees to Stripe for transactions which you can recover from your application fee ($20) on the project. 
But the refund will cost you as there will be no fee earned but still payable to Stripe.

Hope it helps.

- [0 connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect)
- [1 accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts)
- [2 Destination Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges)
- [3 Manual Payouts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#using-manual-payouts)
- [4 Refund](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges#issuing-refunds)